# Why by codeigniter email is going to spam folder with full information?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, email-client, email-spam

Hi i am using CodeIgniter with PHP technology and i am sending emails from application but emails are being sent in spam folder of recipients.

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('aaaa@domain.com', 'MYRegistration');
$this->email->to('abc@domain.com');

$this->email->subject('Congratulation ! You are a User.');
$this->email->message('html code');
$KsbMailStatus = $this->email->send();
```

This email contains some images and links also because this is a registration emails.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line the email is filtered into the spam

```
   $this->email->subject('Congratulation ! You are a User.');
```

Change it to some things else

```
 $this->email->subject('hi thanks for the subscription.');
```

Comment: the alternative is just an example plz avoid the words like congratulation its it marked into spam folder

Comment: @user3424904 plz tell you line

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->email->from('aaaa@domain.com', 'MYRegistration');
```

The from email address 'aaaa@domain.com' should exists.

Change it to a valid email address that is exists.

May resolve your problem